# Trying to connect Ethereum Wallet with ganache-cli on Windows

Tags: web3js, wallets, dapps, ganache-cli

I am trying to connect Ethereum Wallet with Ganache-Cli but it starts looking for geth note instead of ganache-cli. Can someone please tell me the correct way of doing it. Or is there any specific version of Ethereum Wallet support with gangache-cli? Below you can see my ganache-cli is listenting on localhost:8545

[image]

But still when execute *EthereumWallet.exe --rpc http://localhost:8545* it gives me error given below.

[image]

Comment: Please share specific technical details (your code and your ganache-cli configuration).

Comment: @goodvibration kindly see now!

Comment: EthereumWallet is no longer being developed and it doesn't have support anymore. You should use a different wallet.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your reply. Actually i want to call deployed contract functions as we do in Ethereum Wallet can you please suggest me any alternate software for doing it.

Comment: I use remix.ethereum.org together with metamask for that but it is not as elegant as ethereumwallet.